# validating userinput in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I want to redirect the user if the userinput matches a specific value

```
@flask_class.route('/base', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def startpoint():
    form = FirstRiddleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        if form.useranswer.data == 'correct':
            redirect(url_for('passedtest'))
        else:
            redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('base.html', form=form)
```

so far I get no response (no redirect..) when clicking the submit button

is `form.useranswer.data == 'correct'`the correct way to get the userinput ?

form

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class FirstRiddleForm(FlaskForm):
    useranswer = StringField("insert your answer", validators=[DataRequired()])
    submitanswer = SubmitField("Submit")
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>startpoint</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>your journey beginns here, Traveler !</h1><br>
        <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
             {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

            <p>
                {{ form.useranswer.label }}<br>
                {{ form.useranswer(size=32) }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.submitanswer() }}</p>

        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should return your `redirect()`